# Python next nearest specific item (onwards) in a list and check between

Tags: python, list, loops, nearest-neighbor

```
A=['a',1,2,3,'b',4,5,'a',6,7,'b']
```

How do I find the next nearest specific value's index and elements between my current value and it?

I want to iterate through the list A, and be able to find the next nearest given value' index and elemnts in-between. Saying, for example, the sepcific value is 'b', if I am at the point of first 'a', then it will return a's index (0) the first b's index (4) and the  elements in-between (1,2,3). If I am at the point of the second `a`, then it will return a's index (7) the first b's index (10) and the  elements in-between (67).

Thanks

Comment: Will the 'specific value' always be a character? Will they always be 'a' and 'b'? For example, will you ever have a list like `['a', 'a', 1, 2, 'b', 3, 'b']`?

Comment: Don't have to be 'a' or 'b', this is a simplified example for readers to understand. Could be two numbers as well e.g. 3, 6 , but since I not given repeated numbers, it is not so typical.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [15]: result = []
    ...: start = 'a'
    ...: stop = 'b'
    ...: a = A
    ...: accum = 0
    ...: while True:
    ...:     try:
    ...:         i1 = a.index(start)
    ...:         i2 = a.index(stop)
    ...:         result.append((i1+accum, i2+accum, [a[i] for i in range(i1 + 1, i2)]))
    ...:     except ValueError:
    ...:         break
    ...:     accum += i2 + 1
    ...:     a = a[accum:]
    ...:
    ...: result
    ...:
Out[15]: [(0, 4, [1, 2, 3]), (7, 10, [6, 7])]
```

Comment: I should be able to find the second 'b', the index only gives the first 'a''s and 'b''s index.

Comment: uhh, if you read your question you only asked for the first.  I quote you:  " Say the sepcific value is 'b', if I am at the point of first 'a', then it will return a's index (0) the first b's index (4) and the elements in-between (1,2,3)."  How is someone supposed to know where you are 'at' ?

Comment: If you have strange constraints to a problem, you should ask how to make a function, when given certain inputs returns certain outputs.  With your problem, that is not really clear, so I improvised based on what you sounded like you wanted.

Comment: I was saying 'if' I am at  first 'a', but to be more clear, I have modified my question.

Comment: I am saying iterate through the list, I could be at any point. and the given  point does not have to be 'b' as well.

Comment: ok, in programming, usually it works like this:  Given some stuff, return some other stuff...  What values are you giving me to start with (given)?

Comment: are you giving me a starting index, or ..?

Comment: No I mean iterate through the list which means the index is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 for every elemetns

Comment: You are not making sense.  What are the inputs, and what are the expected outputs?  Just list them

Comment: input is the list the a specific value. Like c=[1,2,3,'a'], my input is c and 'a'. It seems you don't understand loop... The result shoudb e 1's index (0), 'a''s index (3) and between value [2,3] and then 2' index (1) and 'a''s index (3) and between value [3], and so on

Comment: So given a list [1,2,3,'a'], and given 'a', you want a function to return what?  A list of lists?  If so, list the list of lists exactly as they should appear.  I understand loops just fine, but you need to phrase the question better so people understand what result you want.  Just literally write out the result.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just the two indexs and elements in-between. If you can get the result, any form would be fine. But you should know what I want is much more complicated than c, it could be ['a','a','b','c','b'], indcluding duplicates....

Comment: ok, given A=['a',1,2,3,'b',4,5,'a',6,7,'b'] and 'a', what is the result?

Comment: ok, how did it know to stop at 4?  You told me that you are given the list A, and given the value 'a'.  You did not mention that you are also given a value 'b' in your most recent posts